# Getting all links with specific inner HTML value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div>
    <a>
       Text1
       <img alt="" stc="" />
    </a>
    <a>
       Text2
    </a>
 </div>
```

I want to select all anchor elements that have `text=text2`.  I'm looking for something like this:

> ```
> $('a[text=Text2]')
> ```

---

**Edit:** Why this is not working? For some some reason, it needs to be in this format:

> ```
> $('div').find('a').find(':contains("Text2")')
> ```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You ask why this doesn't work:

```
$('div').find('a').find(':contains("Text2")')
```

The reason is, [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will search children elements, you want [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (because you already selected the `a` - or you add the `:contains` to the a find:

```
$('div').find('a').filter(':contains("Text2")');
$('div').find('a:contains("Text2")');
```

Comment: Forgot about `.filter()`. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why you didn't change the initial selector to $('div a:contains("Text2")') instead of the Find/Filter chain? jQuery selectors traverse descendants just like CSS selectors do.

Comment: @kevin because of the comment in the op: 'from some reasons it's need to be in this format'

Comment: Also @Kevin Gorski - The speed of the selectors is actually much faster if you use the `.find().filter()` method.  Finding `a` can use `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelectorAll` to optimize.  However the jQuery `:contains()` selector is not supported in CSS3 (QSA) and therefore FORCES that the selector be parsed using sizzle instead of first using the quicker browser selection. http://jsperf.com/quick-selector-test for performance test

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$("a:contains('text2')")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:contains()` filter.

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 2):

As an additional note, rather than scanning for exact text inside a link it might be better to be scanning for attributes, e.g.

```
<div class="farm-market-items">
  <a class="market-item" data-item-type="seed" data-item-id="817">
    Carrot Seed
    <img alt="" src="" class="item-thumb" />
  </a>
  <a class="market-item" data-item-type="seed" data-item-id="25">
    Spinach Seed
  </a>
  <a class="market-item" data-item-type="tree" data-item-id="981">
    Pear Tree
  </a>
</div>
```

Now you can (accurately) scan for:

```
all_seeds = $('a[data-item-type="seed"]');
```

(I'm a big fan of the data-* attributes.)

Comment: From some reason it's need to be in the above format. So I must query it only from the innerText.